# Laravel Authorize Multiple Permission

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-authorization

I want to control the index of my controller via two permissions, the user must have either 'Permission1' or 'Permission2'. Both together is also possible.

Currently I check for one permission:

```
$this->authorize('Permission1');
```

I have tried:

```
$this->authorize('Permission1' || 'Permission2');
$this->authorize(['Permission1' || 'Permission2']);
$this->authorize(['Permission1', 'Permission2']);
```

Controller Constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');

    $this->middleware('permission:' . Permission::PERMSSION1, ['only' => [
        'permission1',
    ]]); // Here I don't know how to adjust it too
}
```

And a few more, but nothing seems to work.

How can I query the authorization for Permission1 OR Permission2?

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried with `$this->authorizeEither('Permission1', 'Permission2');` ?

Comment: Hi :) This might be more appopriate as a comment on the Question. Have you this solution to see if it solves the problem?

Comment: noisedaddy, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).