# $this->authorize('gate-name') in laravel 9 with 2 parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authorization, laravel-gate

I'm learning authorization in laravel 9 using '[gate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#gates)'. In my case, I want to protect my controller so who can access the controller only users who have "delete" and "edit" 'gate'.

Then I created 2 new gates in 'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider' defined as follows:

```
Gate::define('edit', function (User $user) {
    return $user->permission === 'edit';
});

Gate::define('delete', function (User $user) {
    return $user->permission === 'delete';
});
```

Then, I need to add `$this->authorize('edit')` and also `$this->authorize('delete')` in the controller, unfortunately it can't be done, laravel only accept once of `$this->authorize('edit')` or `$this->authorize('edit')`.
The problem is, I have to add 2 conditions there, I also can't write an array as a parameter.

What I want is like this:

```
$this->authorize('edit' && 'delete')
```

Or:

```
$this->authorize(['edit', 'delete'])
```

Unfortunately, I can't add both.
Basically, the user have to pass 2 checks (must have "edit" AND "delete' gate) using the laravel 'gate' feature in my controller.

The check is like this:
"Does that user have edit access"? OR "Does that user have delete access"? if "yes/true", allow entry to the controller, else "return 403"

FOR EASIER EXAMPLES:
I have this controller to delete a post on my web:

```
public function destroy(Post $post)
   {
       $this->authorize('edit'); // I want not only check 'edit', I want to check 'delete' too
       $post->delete();
   }
```

How to apply it?

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70264555/laravel-authorize-multiple-permission) but no answer

Comment: `Gate::allows(...)`, `Gate::check(...)`, etc

Comment: Thanks, man! It works! I just found out laravel has that method. Please write your comment as 'answer' so I can mark it as correct answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Gate` facade to interact with the authorization system and without throwing an exception (just checking gates):

```
if (Gate::check(['edit', 'delete'])) {
    // has all these permissions
} else {
    // does not have all these permissions
}
```